# hpux: ipmon on syslog.log

Tags: hp-ux

I have configured firewall for log,i want to write in a separate file log
for ipmon.
Reading on net they suggest to use local0.* or local0.debug on /etc/syslog.conf file.
I make this

```
local0.notice       /var/adm/syslog/ipmon.log
local0.info     /var/adm/syslog/ipmon.log
local0.err      /var/adm/syslog/ipmon.log
local0.warning      /var/adm/syslog/ipmon.log
```

I have try also local0.debug and local0.*
But instead of write on only ipmon.log,it continue to write on syslog.log
and ipmon.log.
Why?
Of course i have restarted ipmon and syslogd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update syslog.conf to ignore local0.* for syslog.log eg.

```
*.info;mail.none;local0.none      /var/adm/syslog/syslog.log
```

As the first '*.info' will match local0.